# What's the difference Expires and Cache-control:max-age?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

Could you tell me  the difference of Expires and Cache-control:max-age?

Comment: Given information is not enough to understand/answer the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Expires` was defined in the `HTTP/1.0` specifications, and `Cache-Control` in the `HTTP/1.1` specifications.

I would suggest defining both so you cater to both, the older clients that only understand `HTTP/1.0`, and the newer ones.

Answer (score 5):

`Expires` was specified in HTTP 1.0 specification as compared to `Cache-Control: max-age`, which was introduced in the early HTTP 1.1 specification. The value of the `Expires` header has to be in a very specific date and time format, any error in which will make your resources non-cacheable. The `Cache-Control: max-age` header's value when sent to the browser is in seconds, the chances of any error happening in which is quite less.

Since you can specify only one of the two headers in your web.config file, I'd suggest going with the `Cache-Control: max-age` header because of the flexibility it offers in setting a relative timespan from the present date to a date in the future. You can basically set and forget, as compared to the case with `Expires` header, whose value you will have to remember to update at least once every year. And if you set both headers programmatically from within your code, know that the value of `Cache-Control: max-age` header will take precedence over `Expires` header. So, something to keep in mind there as well.

From [Setting Expires and Cache-Control: max-age headers for static resources in ASP.NET](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/expires-and-max-age-headers-in-aspnet/)