# how to set up both httpexpires and cachecontrol headers web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, cache-expiration

Earlier I was asking the question [how to set up both httpexpires and cachecontrol headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826035/asp-net-mvc-how-to-set-up-both-httpexpires-and-cachecontrol-headers)

I think I kind of found the answer

```
<clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" cacheControlMaxAge="12:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
```

Now i am not receiving `500 internal error` for image requests.

**But now I have a new question**

Looks like If I set `cacheControlMode="UseExpires"` it will use `httpExpires` as content expiratoin but if I set `cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"` it will use `cacheControlMaxAge` as content expiration. So still not clear how to set both `cacheControlMaxAge` and `httpExpires`? Is it possible?