# Implementing static files cache in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am trying to implement static files cache in the ASP.net mvc application.

What i did:

I've added into `Content` folder a `web.config` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="300.0:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In the website `web.config` file, i commented out some lines of code:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <!-- Commented them out
      <add verb="GET" path="*.js" name="Static for js" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.css" name="Static for css" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.png" name="Static for png" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.jpg" name="Static for jpg" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      -->
    </handlers>
```

Now, publishing the website and inspecting the resources, i get the folowing response:

[image]

I see is missing the `Expire` header ?! (shouldn't it be there in order for cache to work)

Does the response headers tell the browser to cache the resource for the next 25920000 seconds?

I am doing things correctly in order to cache the static files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct, and you [should be fine](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2007/05/15/expires_max-age).

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947006/63733) might say you should add `Expires`, too, for clients which do not understand HTTP/1.1, but as already argued in the [first linked article](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2007/05/15/expires_max-age), that shouldn't be a real concern, even less now, 7 years later.

Comment: Ok, so as long as i have `Cache-Control: public, max-age=xxxxx` means the browser will cache the resource

Comment: @RaraituL i have the same issue, i was missing the expire header, and google speed test says add expires for images, css, js. did you find any solution ?

Comment: @stom sorry, i just read this comment. I think it was working with `Cache-Control` header